# call variable from different script with powershell

Tags: powershell, variables

I am trying to call a variable from different script, but it's not working as what I wanted.
Currently I have code below to call password variable from another scrip. Is there any ways to make this script work?

```
$password = ‪C:\Users\User\Documents\StorePass.ps1 $password
```

I am trying to call $password variable from StorePass script to use as a $password variable in current file.

Comment: 1st - You should not store passwords in scripts. 2nd - you cannot access variables from other scripts this way. You would need to actually run the script and declare the variables as GLOBAL - what happened to be a bad idea or at least a bad style..

Comment: the usual way to pass values from one script to another is with some form of storage. if you want structured storage, use CSV, JSON, or CliXml. **_the latter will store your password in a per-user-per-machine encrypted form._**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could try dot sourcing the script

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts

Basically, it's run the script in line, bit like Import-Moduel. Anything it does is imported into your session, including variables.

Might also be worth considering a redesign. If you're storing something that both need to access independent of each other, store it outside of both? File system or registry.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/decrypt-powershell-secure-string-password/